# PHPDoc different return type for extended classes

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

I have created my own DB - Model structure which is similar to Laravel. I have been facing with 2 problems.

I have a `Model` class which all of my models extend it. For example, my `User` class extends `Model`. I want to return that `get()` method return type of class which is extended.

Is this possible?

```
Class Model extends DB {
    /**
     * @return AnyClassThatExtended
     */
    function get()
    {
    }
}

Class User extends Model {
    function test() {
        $user->get(); // I want it to return User type of object
    }
}
```

Comment: `@return static`  should do the job. It works just fine -- see for yourself: https://postimg.org/image/41foax7ju3/ . If it does not -- maybe it's because of your code -- then provide better code sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
private static $instance;

/**
 * return static
 */
public function get() {
    if (is_null(self::$instance)) {
        self::$instance = new static();
    }

    return self::$instance;
}
```

because you are returning current class that you are at (if I understand correctly)

*It's possible that PHPStorm does not recognize it*

Comment: I have tried it on PHPStorm and as you said it did not recognize. It thinks like i am returning a Model object. Atom worked it smoothly. So it looks like there is no other way for PHPStorm. Thanks for the help!